# Delphi JSON superobject saving multiple objects to file in alphabetical order

Tags: json, delphi, superobject

I'm using the JSON superobject library to save objects to a file. When my code worked, they were written with proper formatting.

```
procedure TDCell.Save(fileName: string);
var i,j : integer;
    JsonObjCol1, JsonObjCol2, JsonObjCol3, JsonObjCol4: ISuperObject;
begin
  JsonArray := SO();
  JsonObjCol1 := SO();
  JsonObjCol2 := SO();
  JsonObjCol3 := SO();
  JsonObjCol4 := SO();
  for i := 0 to Table.ColCount - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to Table.RowCount - 1 do
begin
  if Table.Objects[i, j] is TEdit then
    with Table.Objects[i, j] as TEdit do
      case i of
        0:JsonArray[Name] := SO(Table.Cells[i, j]);
        1:JsonObjCol1[Name] := SO(Table.Cells[i, j]);
        2:JsonObjCol2[Name] := SO(Table.Cells[i, j]);
        3:JsonObjCol3[Name] := SO(Table.Cells[i, j]);
        4:JsonObjCol4[Name] := SO(Table.Cells[i, j]);
      end
  else
  if Table.Objects[i, j] is TLabel then
    with Table.Objects[i, j] as TLabel do
      case i of
        0:JsonArray[Name] := SO(Caption);
        1:JsonObjCol1[Name] := SO(Caption);
        2:JsonObjCol2[Name] := SO(Caption);
        3:JsonObjCol3[Name] := SO(Caption);
        4:JsonObjCol4[Name] := SO(Caption);
      end
end;
case i of
  0:JsonObject['Col' + IntToStr(Table.ColCount - 1 - i)] := JsonArray;
  1:JsonObject['Col' + IntToStr(Table.ColCount - 1 - i)] := JsonObjCol1;
  2:JsonObject['Col' + IntToStr(Table.ColCount - 1 - i)] := JsonObjCol2;
  3:JsonObject['Col' + IntToStr(Table.ColCount - 1 - i)] := JsonObjCol3;
  4:JsonObject['Col' + IntToStr(Table.ColCount - 1 - i)] := JsonObjCol4;
end;
  end;
  JsonObject.SaveTo(fileName, true);
end;
```

`JsonArray` also has type `ISuperObject`

But it seems that there is some opposite order sorting feature running in this library. Not only objects but also key-value pairs in them are written in opposite alphabetical order.

```
{
 "Col4": {
  "Label03": "Hello03",
  "Label01": "Hello01",
  "Edit04": "Hello04",
  "Edit02": "Hello02",
  "Edit00": "Hello00"
 },
 "Col3": {
  "Label13": "Hello13",
  "Label11": "Hello11",
  "Edit14": "Hello14",
  "Edit12": "Hello12",
  "Edit10": "Hello10"
 },
 "Col2": {
  "Label23": "Hello23",
  "Label21": "Hello21",
  "Edit24": "Hello24",
  "Edit22": "Hello22",
  "Edit20": "Hello20"
 },
 "Col1": {
  "Label33": "Hello33",
  "Label31": "Hello31",
  "Edit34": "Hello34",
  "Edit32": "Hello32",
  "Edit30": "Hello30"
 },
 "Col0": {
  "Label43": "Hello43",
  "Label41": "Hello41",
  "Edit44": "Hello44",
  "Edit42": "Hello42",
  "Edit40": "Hello40"
 }
}
```

What should I do to make superobject write the file in the proper order? I've tested that objects are added in the proper order in cycles. The file must look like this.

```
{
 "Col0": {
  "Edit00": "Hello00",
  "Label01": "Hello01",
  "Edit02": "Hello02",
  "Label03": "Hello03",
  "Edit04": "Hello04"
 },
 "Col1": {
  "Edit10": "Hello10",
  "Label11": "Hello11",
  "Edit12": "Hello12",      
  "Label13": "Hello13",    
  "Edit14": "Hello14"
 },
 and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **proper** order. The elements of a JSON object can be presented in any order, and the [JSON standard](http://json.org/) makes it clear that the meaning of the file cannot depend on the order of the elements of a JSON object:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

If you require ordered data then you need to use a JSON array:

> An array is an ordered collection of values.

Comment: So I have to rewright my Load method to get proper loading from file. Anyway thank you.

Comment: And yes, the code in SuperObject *happens to* write out items in reverse order. I use that to present items in an order that is pleasant for the human reader, but it could break with any Superobject upgrade.